# Run neo4j Windows service under a less-privileged service account

Tags: neo4j, install4j

I'm using neo4j v3.5.  Is there a way to run neo4j as a Windows service under a less-privileged service account?  I'm currently using the **"neo4j.bat install-service"** command to install the service on Windows.  This command runs the service under the predefined SYSTEM/LocalSystem account available in Windows.  The "LocalSystem" account has extensive privileges, however, so I would like to create a less privileged Windows account to run the neo4j service.  Has anyone done this before using automated commands or batch/Powershell scripts?

Answer (score 0):

I used this 3rd party tool called psexec: https://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html.  I can run batch files from a local machine (or even remote) using a different id/password. Give it a try.

For example:

```
psexec \\workstation64 -c "<full_path_here>\neo4j.bat install-service" -u LESS_PRIV_USER -p LESS_PRIV_USER_PASSWORD
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @jose_bacoy.  I did a little research on psexec and I'm not sure it will be suitable for our requirements, though.  We are using a tool called install4j to create an installer our clients will use to install our application in their Windows environments.  Apparently psexec is known for being used in malware and could potentially get our installer flagged as a threat by anti-virus tools, which we obviously want to avoid.  Ideally we would like to utilize tools/commands already built into Windows and then use a batch script from within our installer to run them.